# Adding a xml output to existing xml element

Tags: php, xml

I am trying to add the output of this Php file:

```
<?php

      include "dbcon.php";
      //include "GUID_Generator.php";
      //$caseID = $_REQUEST['caseID'];
      $caseID = "160000000091000002000000009101";
      $query_tb_prescript = "select doseUnit,frequency,medicineID,startDate, EndDate from tb_prescript where caseID = '$caseID'";
      $result_tb_prescript = mysql_query($query_tb_prescript) or die();
      while($row_tb_prescript = mysql_fetch_array($result_tb_prescript)){
      $doseUnit = $row_tb_prescript['doseUnit'];
      $frequency = $row_tb_prescript['frequency'];
      $medicineID = $row_tb_prescript['medicineID'];
      $startDate = $row_tb_prescript['startDate'];
      $EndDate = $row_tb_prescript['EndDate'];
    // GUID
    $first_code_tbcase = date("Ymd");
    $second_code_tbcase = mt_rand(1000, 9999);
    $third_code_tbcase = mt_rand(1000, 9999);
    $fourth_code_tbcase = mt_rand(1000, 9999);
    $fifth_code_tbcase = mt_rand(1000,9999).mt_rand(1000,9999).mt_rand(1000, 9999);
   $GUID = $first_code_tbcase.'-'.$second_code_tbcase.'-'.$third_code_tbcase.'-'.$fourth_code_tbcase.'-'.$fifth_code_tbcase;


   $query_medicine = "select name1,strength, strengthUnit from medicine where id = '$medicineID'";
      $result_medicine = mysql_query($query_medicine) or die();
      $row_medicine = mysql_fetch_array($result_medicine);
      $medicineName = $row_medicine['name1'];
      $medicinestrength = $row_medicine['strength'];
      $medicinestrengthUnit = $row_medicine['strengthUnit'];

$xml_medication = '<Medications>
  <Medication guid="'.$GUID.'" Medication="'.$medicineName.'" DoseUnit="'.$medicinestrengthUnit.'" DoseFrequency="'.$frequency.'" Dose="'.$medicinestrength .'" DateEnd="'.$EndDate.'" DateStart="'.$startDate.'">
    <Customattributes>
      <AttributeKey Archive="false" Name="Route"></AttributeKey>
      <AttributeKey Archive="false" Name="Days/week">'.$frequency.'</AttributeKey>
      <AttributeKey Archive="false" Name="Still On Medication"></AttributeKey>
      <AttributeKey Archive="false" Name="Indication"></AttributeKey>
      <AttributeKey Archive="false" Name="Type of Indication"></AttributeKey>
      <AttributeKey Archive="false" Name="Reason For Stopping"></AttributeKey>
      <AttributeKey Archive="false" Name="Occupation"></AttributeKey>
      <AttributeKey Archive="false" Name="Clinician action taken with regard to medicine if related to AE"></AttributeKey>
      <AttributeKey Archive="false" Name="Batch Number"></AttributeKey>
      <AttributeKey Archive="false" Name="EFFECT OF DECHALLENGE (D) &amp; RECHALLENGE (R)"></AttributeKey>
    </Customattributes>
  </Medication>
</Medications>';


  echo $xml_medication;

}

?>
```

to the out put of this file.(SAMPLE2.php)

```
  <?php

     include "dbcon.php";
     //$caseID = $_REQUEST['caseID'];
     //include "queries.php";
     //include "medicationsloop3.php";
     error_reporting('0'); 
     ini_set('display_errors', 1);
     // Generate GUIDs -------------------------------------------------------------

// GUID for TB Case
$query_guid_tbcase = "select * from `interop_id` where caseID = '$caseID'";
$result_guid_tbcase = mysql_query($query_guid_tbcase) or die();
$total_guid_tbcase = mysql_num_rows($result_guid_tbcase);
$row_guid_tbcase = mysql_fetch_array($result_guid_tbcase);

  if($total_guid_tbcase == 0){
    // GUID
    $first_code_tbcase = date("Ymd");
    $second_code_tbcase = mt_rand(1000, 9999);
    $third_code_tbcase = mt_rand(1000, 9999);
    $fourth_code_tbcase = mt_rand(1000, 9999);
    $fifth_code_tbcase = mt_rand(1000, 9999).mt_rand(1000, 9999).mt_rand(1000, 9999);
    $guid_code_tbcase = $first_code_tbcase.'-'.$second_code_tbcase.'-'.$third_code_tbcase.'-'.$fourth_code_tbcase.'-'.$fifth_code_tbcase;
  }else{
    $guid_code_tbcase = $row_guid_tbcase['GUID'];
  }

$subscriber = 'PH-ITIS-001';
$xml_payload = '<Patients>
<Patient guid="20161208-9093-4438-8722-714450479963" FirstName ="RANCE" Surname = "REMEDIO" MiddleName = "RANA" CreatedDate = "2016-12-08 08:48:20" LastUpdated = "2016-12-08 08:48:20" DateOfBirth="1987-03-08" Facility="09 - Sorsogon Medical Mission Group Hospital" Archive="false">
<Customattributes>
<AttributeKey Archive="false" Name="Medical Record Number">DR-TB0000002</AttributeKey>
<AttributeKey Archive="false" Name="Patient Identity Number">16000000009</AttributeKey>
<AttributeKey Archive="false" Name="Identity Type">9MTR Study</AttributeKey>
 <AttributeKey Archive="false" Name="Gender">Male</AttributeKey>
 <AttributeKey Archive="false" Name="MaritalStatus">MARRIED</AttributeKey>
 <AttributeKey Archive="false" Name="Employment Status">Employed</AttributeKey>
  <AttributeKey Archive="false" Name="Occupation">PROGRAMMER</AttributeKey>
 <AttributeKey Archive="false" Name="Language"></AttributeKey>
 <AttributeKey Archive="false" Name="Address">1241 MACARIO SACAY STREET</AttributeKey>
  <AttributeKey Archive="false" Name="Address Line 2">MAKATI CITY</AttributeKey>
  <AttributeKey Archive="false" Name="City">MAKATI CITY</AttributeKey>
  <AttributeKey Archive="false" Name="State"></AttributeKey>
  <AttributeKey Archive="false" Name="Postal Code">1232</AttributeKey>
  <AttributeKey Archive="false" Name="Patient Contact Number">+639973771272</AttributeKey>
  <AttributeKey Archive="false" Name="Country of Birth">Philippines</AttributeKey>
   <AttributeKey Archive="false" Name="Medical Record Number Type">DR-TB</AttributeKey>
 </Customattributes>
 <the medication tag will be put here!!!!>
 <LabTests>
 <LabTest guid="a0002d35-a804-fe4b-e943-abc2300040F4" LabValue="1" TestUnit="" LabTest="Chest X-Ray" TestResult="Positive" TestDate="2016-03-04">
  <Customattributes>
     <AttributeKey Archive="false" Name="Remarks">Chest X-Ray results are in</AttributeKey>
  </Customattributes>
  </LabTest>
  </LabTests>
  <Conditions>
  <Condition guid="b4ccd4a3-2354-6456-a4c3-abc04e0002Be" DateEnd="2016-10-04" DateStart="2016-01-04" TreatmentStartDate="2016-03-04" Terminology="10019805">
   <Customattributes>
   <AttributeKey Archive="false" Name="Condition Ongoing"></AttributeKey>
   </Customattributes>
   </Condition>
   </Conditions>
   <ClinicalEvents>
       <ClinicalEvent guid="b4ccd4a3-2354-5678-1234-abc04e00045f" SourceDescription="Headache" SourceTerminology="10019805" ResolutionDate="2016-10-04" OnsetDate="2016-04-04">
         <Customattributes>
           <AttributeKey Archive="false" Name="Outcome">Resolving</AttributeKey>
           <AttributeKey Archive="false" Name="Intensity (Severity)">Moderate</AttributeKey>
           <AttributeKey Archive="false" Name="Severity Grading Scale">WHO Scale</AttributeKey>
           <AttributeKey Archive="false" Name="Severity Grade">Grade 1</AttributeKey>
           <AttributeKey Archive="false" Name="Is the adverse event serious?">Yes</AttributeKey>
           <AttributeKey Archive="false" Name="Seriousness"></AttributeKey>
           <AttributeKey Archive="false" Name="Admission Date">2016-09-04</AttributeKey>
           <AttributeKey Archive="false" Name="Discharge Date"></AttributeKey>
           <AttributeKey Archive="false" Name="Date of Death"></AttributeKey>
           <AttributeKey Archive="false" Name="Autopsy Done"></AttributeKey>
           <AttributeKey Archive="false" Name="Was the AE attributed to one or more drugs?">Yes</AttributeKey>
           <AttributeKey Archive="false" Name="Was the event reported to national PV?">Yes</AttributeKey>
           <AttributeKey Archive="false" Name="Full Name of Reporter"></AttributeKey>
          <AttributeKey Archive="false" Name="Date of Report">2016-09-22</AttributeKey>
          <AttributeKey Archive="false" Name="Outcome"></AttributeKey>
          <AttributeKey Archive="false" Name="Type of Reporter">Other health professional</AttributeKey>
          <AttributeKey Archive="false" Name="Reporter Contact Number">9876543456</AttributeKey>
          <AttributeKey Archive="false" Name="Expected or Unexpected AE">         </AttributeKey>
          <AttributeKey Archive="false" Name="Treatment of Reaction">No Treatment</AttributeKe y>
       </Customattributes>
     </ClinicalEvent>
   </ClinicalEvents>
       <Encounters>
        <Encounter guid="1111be4a-eebb-bb3e-a4c3-a4d14e12344f" EncounterType="Pre-Treatment Visit" EncounterDate="2016-04-04">
        <InstanceValues>
        <InstanceValue Archive="false" ElementName="Weight (kg)">67</InstanceValue>
        <InstanceValue Archive="false" ElementName="Height (cm)">172</InstanceValue>
        <InstanceValue Archive="false" ElementName="Indication for Treatment (TB)">Pulmonary TB</InstanceValue>
        <InstanceValue Archive="false" ElementName="Previous TB treatment?">Yes</InstanceValue>
        <InstanceValue Archive="false" ElementName="Pregnancy Status">NA</InstanceValue>
        <InstanceValue Archive="false" ElementName="Date of last menstrual period">NA</InstanceValue>
        <InstanceValue Archive="false" ElementName="Estimated gestation (weeks)"></InstanceValue>
        <InstanceValue Archive="false" ElementName="Breastfeeding mother"></InstanceValue>
        <InstanceValue Archive="false" ElementName="Site of TB"></InstanceValue>
        <InstanceValue Archive="false" ElementName="Injecting Drug Use Within Past Year"></InstanceValue>
         <InstanceValue Archive="false" ElementName="Excessive alcohol use within the past year"></InstanceValue>
       <InstanceValue Archive="false" ElementName="Tobacco use within the past year"></InstanceValue>
      <InstanceValue Archive="false" ElementName="Documented HIV infection"></InstanceValue>
      <InstanceValue Archive="false" ElementName="Baseline Chest Xray Presentation"></InstanceValue>
      <InstanceValue Archive="false" ElementName="Ever received treatment with first line anti-TB drugs for &gt;-1 month prior to this episode?"> </InstanceValue>
      <InstanceValue Archive="false" ElementName="Ever received treatment with second line anti-TB drugs for &gt;-1 month prior to this episode?"> </InstanceValue>
      <InstanceValue Archive="false" ElementName="Isoniazid susceptibility by any laboratory test(s)">Susceptible</InstanceValue>
      <InstanceValue Archive="false" ElementName="Isoniazid confirmation">Xpert</InstanceValue>
      <InstanceValue Archive="false" ElementName="Rifampicin susceptibility by any laboratory test(s)"> </InstanceValue>
      <InstanceValue Archive="false" ElementName="Rifampicin confirmation"> </InstanceValue>
     </InstanceValues>
      </Encounter>
     </Encounters>
     </Patient>
     </Patients>';  

 $xml_body = '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
      <soap:Envelope xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
        xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
          <soap:Body>
            <Interop_Push xmlns="http://sample.org/webservices/">
               <subscriber>'.$subscriber.'</subscriber>
                <payload>
                  <![CDATA['.$xml_payload.']]>    
                </payload>
            </Interop_Push>
          </soap:Body>
      </soap:Envelope>';     


        echo $xml_body;

     $header = array(
          "POST: /webservice/InteropGeneric.asmx HTTP/1.1",
          "Host: example.net",
          "Content-Type: text/xml; charset=utf-8",
          "Content-Length: ".strlen($xml_body),
          "SOAPAction: http://sample.org/webservices/Interop_Push"
          );  

    $url = 'http://example.net/webservice/InteropGeneric.asmx';

$ch = curl_init(); 
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
  curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, COOKIE_FILE_PATH); 
  curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE, COOKIE_FILE_PATH); 
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPAUTH, CURLAUTH_ANY);
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, false);
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1); 
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 300); 
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $header);
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $xml_body); 

  $result = curl_exec($ch);
  $status = curl_getinfo($ch, CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE);

  $doc = new DOMDocument();
  $doc->loadXML($result);
  $doc2 =  $doc->getElementsByTagName('Interop_PushResult')->item(0)->nodeValue;
  $response = $doc2;
  $reponse2 = array("Update completed successfully");
  $response3 = array("example.net");

  $newresponse = str_replace($reponse2, $response3, $response);

     echo $newresponse;

     die;

     curl_close($ch);

    ?>
```

What i wanted to do is to display the output (Xml file structure when viewed on source code) of sample1.php to the output of sample2.php (Xml file structure when viewed on source code). so that i can have a complete xml file of a patient info.

Kindly help!

Comment: Are both files saved as .xml files or remain PHP strings/objects?

Comment: both are save as PHP file. but i want to add the result of sample1 to the xml result of sample2

Comment: PHP file? PHP is a script whereas XML is data. Also, the second XML is not well-formed. Does opening `<Patient>` tag close at end to serve as root? If you post code, it will help understand your workflow.

Comment: yes,  the <Patient> tag has a close tag i dont know why it doesnt appear.

Comment: @Parfait the first file is the result of the medicationsloop.php that i created where in i query the medications of a patients and put in a loop so that i can have multiple results of medication

Comment: Can you post your PHP code? XML is not code.

Comment: it is too long to be posted here as a comment

Comment: You can edit your own post. In fact the revisions history show you did this once. See edit link just below the tags. We always recommend to never post code in comments.

Comment: i have already edited the file

Comment: what i want to do is to [put the output of the said php file to the <the medication tag will be put here!!!!> for me to be able to have a complete xml file of a patient record

Comment: Much better. And where is the *Patient* xml? Is it a file on disk as .xml?

Comment: nope it is included to another php file..

wait let me edit my file.

Comment: already edited the file

Answer (score 0):

Consider dumping both XML files to disk in both scripts which can be deleted later:

```
file_put_contents('Patients.xml', $xml_payload);

file_put_contents('Medications.xml', $xml_medication);
```

Then merge the two with [XSLT](https://www.w3.org/Style/XSL/), the declarative special-purpose langauge designed to manipulate XML documents. PHP has a built-in XSLT 1.0 processor, [libxslt](http://xmlsoft.org/libxslt/), which you have to enable in .ini by uncommenting the [php_xsl](http://php.net/manual/en/book.xsl.php) item. Specifically, XSLT has the `document()` function allowing it to retrieve nodes from external files. To work properly, files should be in same directory. XSLT also pretty prints!

**XSLT** Script *(save externally as .xsl file)*

```
<xsl:transform xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0">
 <xsl:output version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes" />
 <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

  <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="Patient">
   <xsl:copy>
     <xsl:apply-templates select="@*"/>
     <xsl:copy-of select="Customattributes"/>
     <xsl:copy-of select="document('Medications.xml')/Medication"/>
     <xsl:apply-templates select="node()[name()!='Customattributes']"/>
   </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>  

</xsl:transform>
```

**PHP** Script *(notice Medications.xml is never referenced below only in XSLT above)*

```
// LOAD XML 
$dom = new DOMDocument();
$dom->load('Patients.xml');

// LOAD XSL
$xsl = new DOMDocument();
$xsl->load('XSLTScript.xsl');

// INITIALIZE TRANSFORMER
$proc = new XSLTProcessor;
$proc->importStyleSheet($xsl); 

// TRANSFORM XML
$newXML = $proc->transformToXML($dom);

// SAVE FILE    
file_put_contents('Output.xml', $newXML);

// DELETE SOURCE FILES
unlink('Patients.xml')
unlink('Medications.xml')
```

**Output**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Patients>
  <Patient guid="20161208-9093-4438-8722-714450479963" FirstName="RANCE" Surname="REMEDIO" MiddleName="RANA" CreatedDate="2016-12-08 08:48:20" LastUpdated="2016-12-08 08:48:20" DateOfBirth="1987-03-08" Facility="09 - Sorsogon Medical Mission Group Hospital" Archive="false">
    <Customattributes>
      <AttributeKey Archive="false" Name="Medical Record Number">DR-TB0000002</AttributeKey>
      <AttributeKey Archive="false" Name="Patient Identity Number">16000000009</AttributeKey>
      <AttributeKey Archive="false" Name="Identity Type">9MTR Study</AttributeKey>
      <AttributeKey Archive="false" Name="Gender">Male</AttributeKey>
      <AttributeKey Archive="false" Name="MaritalStatus">MARRIED</AttributeKey>
      <AttributeKey Archive="false" Name="Employment Status">Employed</AttributeKey>
      <AttributeKey Archive="false" Name="Occupation">PROGRAMMER</AttributeKey>
      <AttributeKey Archive="false" Name="Language"/>
      <AttributeKey Archive="false" Name="Address">1241 MACARIO SACAY STREET</AttributeKey>
      <AttributeKey Archive="false" Name="Address Line 2">MAKATI CITY</AttributeKey>
      <AttributeKey Archive="false" Name="City">MAKATI CITY</AttributeKey>
      <AttributeKey Archive="false" Name="State"/>
      <AttributeKey Archive="false" Name="Postal Code">1232</AttributeKey>
      <AttributeKey Archive="false" Name="Patient Contact Number">+639973771272</AttributeKey>
      <AttributeKey Archive="false" Name="Country of Birth">Philippines</AttributeKey>
      <AttributeKey Archive="false" Name="Medical Record Number Type">DR-TB</AttributeKey>
    </Customattributes>
    <Medication guid="20161219-3747-9290-8909-957289965585" Medication="Kanamycin" DoseUnit="mg" DoseFrequency="7" Dose="500" DateEnd="2016-12-15" DateStart="2016-12-08">
      <Customattributes>
        <AttributeKey Archive="false" Name="Route"/>
        <AttributeKey Archive="false" Name="Days/week">7</AttributeKey>
        <AttributeKey Archive="false" Name="Still On Medication"/>
        <AttributeKey Archive="false" Name="Indication"/>
        <AttributeKey Archive="false" Name="Type of Indication"/>
        <AttributeKey Archive="false" Name="Reason For Stopping"/>
        <AttributeKey Archive="false" Name="Occupation"/>
        <AttributeKey Archive="false" Name="Clinician action taken with regard to medicine if related to AE"/>
        <AttributeKey Archive="false" Name="Batch Number"/>
        <AttributeKey Archive="false" Name="EFFECT OF DECHALLENGE (D) &amp; RECHALLENGE (R)"/>
      </Customattributes>
    </Medication>
    <LabTests>
      <LabTest guid="a0002d35-a804-fe4b-e943-abc2300040F4" LabValue="1" TestUnit="" LabTest="Chest X-Ray" TestResult="Positive" TestDate="2016-03-04">
        <Customattributes>
          <AttributeKey Archive="false" Name="Remarks">Chest X-Ray results are in</AttributeKey>
        </Customattributes>
      </LabTest>
    </LabTests>
    <Conditions>
      <Condition guid="b4ccd4a3-2354-6456-a4c3-abc04e0002Be" DateEnd="2016-10-04" DateStart="2016-01-04" TreatmentStartDate="2016-03-04" Terminology="10019805">
        <Customattributes>
          <AttributeKey Archive="false" Name="Condition Ongoing"/>
        </Customattributes>
      </Condition>
    </Conditions>
    <ClinicalEvents>
      <ClinicalEvent guid="b4ccd4a3-2354-5678-1234-abc04e00045f" SourceDescription="Headache" SourceTerminology="10019805" ResolutionDate="2016-10-04" OnsetDate="2016-04-04">
        <Customattributes>
          <AttributeKey Archive="false" Name="Outcome">Resolving</AttributeKey>
          <AttributeKey Archive="false" Name="Intensity (Severity)">Moderate</AttributeKey>
          <AttributeKey Archive="false" Name="Severity Grading Scale">WHO Scale</AttributeKey>
          <AttributeKey Archive="false" Name="Severity Grade">Grade 1</AttributeKey>
          <AttributeKey Archive="false" Name="Is the adverse event serious?">Yes</AttributeKey>
          <AttributeKey Archive="false" Name="Seriousness"/>
          <AttributeKey Archive="false" Name="Admission Date">2016-09-04</AttributeKey>
          <AttributeKey Archive="false" Name="Discharge Date"/>
          <AttributeKey Archive="false" Name="Date of Death"/>
          <AttributeKey Archive="false" Name="Autopsy Done"/>
          <AttributeKey Archive="false" Name="Was the AE attributed to one or more drugs?">Yes</AttributeKey>
          <AttributeKey Archive="false" Name="Was the event reported to national PV?">Yes</AttributeKey>
          <AttributeKey Archive="false" Name="Full Name of Reporter"/>
          <AttributeKey Archive="false" Name="Date of Report">2016-09-22</AttributeKey>
          <AttributeKey Archive="false" Name="Outcome"/>
          <AttributeKey Archive="false" Name="Type of Reporter">Other health professional</AttributeKey>
          <AttributeKey Archive="false" Name="Reporter Contact Number">9876543456</AttributeKey>
          <AttributeKey Archive="false" Name="Expected or Unexpected AE"/>
          <AttributeKey Archive="false" Name="Treatment of Reaction">No Treatment</AttributeKey>
        </Customattributes>
      </ClinicalEvent>
    </ClinicalEvents>
    <Encounters>
      <Encounter guid="1111be4a-eebb-bb3e-a4c3-a4d14e12344f" EncounterType="Pre-Treatment Visit" EncounterDate="2016-04-04">
        <InstanceValues>
          <InstanceValue Archive="false" ElementName="Weight (kg)">67</InstanceValue>
          <InstanceValue Archive="false" ElementName="Height (cm)">172</InstanceValue>
          <InstanceValue Archive="false" ElementName="Indication for Treatment (TB)">Pulmonary TB</InstanceValue>
          <InstanceValue Archive="false" ElementName="Previous TB treatment?">Yes</InstanceValue>
          <InstanceValue Archive="false" ElementName="Pregnancy Status">NA</InstanceValue>
          <InstanceValue Archive="false" ElementName="Date of last menstrual period">NA</InstanceValue>
          <InstanceValue Archive="false" ElementName="Estimated gestation (weeks)"/>
          <InstanceValue Archive="false" ElementName="Breastfeeding mother"/>
          <InstanceValue Archive="false" ElementName="Site of TB"/>
          <InstanceValue Archive="false" ElementName="Injecting Drug Use Within Past Year"/>
          <InstanceValue Archive="false" ElementName="Excessive alcohol use within the past year"/>
          <InstanceValue Archive="false" ElementName="Tobacco use within the past year"/>
          <InstanceValue Archive="false" ElementName="Documented HIV infection"/>
          <InstanceValue Archive="false" ElementName="Baseline Chest Xray Presentation"/>
          <InstanceValue Archive="false" ElementName="Ever received treatment with first line anti-TB drugs for &gt;-1 month prior to this episode?"/>
          <InstanceValue Archive="false" ElementName="Ever received treatment with second line anti-TB drugs for &gt;-1 month prior to this episode?"/>
          <InstanceValue Archive="false" ElementName="Isoniazid susceptibility by any laboratory test(s)">Susceptible</InstanceValue>
          <InstanceValue Archive="false" ElementName="Isoniazid confirmation">Xpert</InstanceValue>
          <InstanceValue Archive="false" ElementName="Rifampicin susceptibility by any laboratory test(s)"/>
          <InstanceValue Archive="false" ElementName="Rifampicin confirmation"/>
        </InstanceValues>
      </Encounter>
    </Encounters>
  </Patient>
</Patients>
```